# Efficient synchronization of the SQLite db -- automatic chunking vs. hints from the web service?

Tags: android, web-services, synchronization, data-synchronization

**Summary:** Are there any well know techniques for **chunking the data for synchronization**? The chunk is considered a block of data that is transmitted separately.

This may be a rather broad question. When suggested, I will start the more specialized topic.

I am going to design/write the code for synchronizing Android tablet database (SQLite) with the central database accessed via a web service. The mechanism should reflect the following facts:

1. It will be used for the range of applications. The applications are to be rather simple. Anyway, they should work mostly off-line.
2. The quantity of data can be from small to huge (up to the technical limits of the tablet).
3. The web service implementation may be a customer-dependent (i.e. the application must not require to rewrite the web service; say, there may be a historical reasons to keep SOAP and not to force REST).
4. In some cases, the specific new web service can be created for the application (using the same technology at the customer site).

The core of the question is how to minimize the size of the data moved during synchronization. The question **is not on how to implement asynchronous download**. (I am cosidering implementation techniques presented in [Developing Android REST client applications](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html) by Virgil Dobjanschi.)

So far, I have found the following basic ways (not in a specific order):

1. Brute force for a small amount of data, i.e. receive/send everything, resolve the differences at the target side (on tablet when downloading, on remote server when uploading). Here (say) the whole database table can be seen as the maximal possible chunk of data.
2. Using the modification date (timestamp) for the records of the data, and synchronising only the newer records based on the remembered dates from the last synchronization. This is fine as is for the added and modified records; however, some aditional mechanism must be used for the deleted records. Here a single record can be considered a minimal possible chunk of data.

The above is for *synchronization of a single chunk of data*. The more realistic situation requires chunking of more records. Here I consider the chunk to be a block of data that can be transmitted separately. When the transmission fails (i.e. being off-line for various reasons), only the failed and the non-transfered chunks must be synchronized.

What is clear to me is that the chunk should have certain size (to form a data block say about 10 kB).

To reduce the communication cost, the constructed chunk package should remain the same until some of the record of the chunk changes, is added, or is removed. The chunk should be constructed as the same independently on whether it is constructed at the central server side, or at the tablet device.

The other chunks should not be affected by the chunk that contains the changed data. This way, say SHA digests could be calculated for each of the chunk on both sides, and it could be easily found what chunks should be synchronized.

Are there any standard techniques, papers, examples on how to determine the chunks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In our [Rethync SDK](https://www.eldos.com/rethync/) framework (open-source) we went the following route: the state information of each object is an opaque field (one can use a timestamp or hash of the data or some unique markers - that's left for developers to decide). Synchronization core compares the value of this field with the saved state and then decides whether the object needs to be uploaded, downloaded, deleted etc.

This approach requires that the state is saved after synchronization (the framework lets you save the state) and used as a basis for detection of changes during the next synchronization.

I welcome you to check Rethync cause it does exactly what you are implementing now.